# Why does Windows command prompt stall until a key is pressed when executing long batch files?

Tags: windows, perl, command-line, windows-xp

When I am running a long batch file,the command prompt hangs.
But,when press  enter,it continues without any problem.

Why does this happen? And is there any way to keep this from happening?

Comment: Perhaps you should show your code.

Comment: Is this a Windows Batch program or a Perl script? You have `perl` as a tag, but you said this was a _batch script_. You need to give us more information. Maybe post the script, or a piece of it. If it's too long, go to [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/), post it there, and give us the link.

Answer (score 0):

It's very difficult to answer a question like this without being able to see the batch file itself. However, from your description, it seems likely that somewhere in there is a call to the `pause` batch command. That would provide the behaviour you say you're experiencing.

If it's unnecessary to have the pause in there, you can probably safely remove the `pause` line. You may prefer to comment it out.